# Accessing dynamic table stored procedure using linq and show result in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, dynamic

I'm creating a dynamic procedure in which I  pass the table name and two search fields names, when I call the stored procedure from the application using LINQ and pass the result to a datagridview, no data is returned.

The stored procedure is working well in the SQL Server side.

This is the stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Shr].[spDinamicTableName]
    @tableName nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @DataField1 nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @DataField2 nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @DataField3 nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @F1Name nvarchar(100)= NULL,
    @F1Value  nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @F2Name nvarchar(100)= NULL,
    @F2Value nvarchar(100)= NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [Shr].' +QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' WHERE 1=1 ' 

    IF @F1Name IS NOT NULL
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND ' +   QUOTENAME(@F1Name)+ ' = @F1 '

    IF @F2Name IS NOT NULL
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND  ' +   QUOTENAME(@F2Name)+ ' like ' + '@F2' 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, 
                          N'@F1 nvarchar(100),@F2 nvarchar(100)',
                          @F1=@F1Value, @F2=@F2Value
END
```

The C# code :

```
    private void TxEmpName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                using (IerpsEntities ierpsEntities = new IerpsEntities())
                {
                    DgvMain.DataSource = ierpsEntities.spDinamicTableName(FilterTableName, FilterSelectF1, FilterSelectF2, FilterSelectF3
                                                    , FilterWhereOrg, FilterWhereOrgValue,FilterWhereF2,TxEmpName.Text);              
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, there are two options you could try, first, you can run the SQL profiler and see what kind of select statements are being executed and verify the expected where conditions are added to the query if that is working run the statement outside of data-bind and see whether it returns any data collection. if all works probably it could be a data binding issue.

Comment: What's the C# definition of `ierpsEntities.spDinamicTableName`? According to the posted code the procedure is named `spDinamicTableName2` in the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a mistake the name should be spDinamicTableName. I'm  using ADO.net entity framework, ierpsEntities is an object of Dbcontext class which responsible for the connection to the database  and spDinamicTableName is the method defined to handle the stored procedure

Comment: I noticed also that the ToList method is not available at the end of : ierpsEntities.spDinamicTableName()